# Сравнение двух одномерных массивов C#

Tags: c#, строки

День добрый, ситуация следующая:

- копируем массив, в составе которого N строк StringBuilder
- в изначально массиве, в каждой строке производим замену ОО на ++
- проверяем скопированный массив с изначального массива, с измененным массивом.

Вопрос:

- даже если замена не производится, т.е. условий для замены нету, при сравнении итоговых массивов возвращается false

  Почему? Что такого делает Replace кроме как поиска и замены?

  ```
  StringBuilder[] raws1 = new StringBuilder[n];

  Array.Copy(raws, raws1, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      raws[i] = raws[i].Replace("OO", "++");
  }

  if (Equals(raws1,raws))
  {
      Console.WriteLine("NO");
  }
  else
  {
      Console.WriteLine("YES");
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0}", raws[i]);
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: StringBuilder not a String

Comment: Код метода `Equals(raws1,raws)` надо бы добавить.

Comment: Заменен сейчас на `Array.Equals(raws1,raws)` ситуация не изменилась. 
Причем массив raws1 копируется. 
Но вот сравнение выдает false

Comment: @Jalt Уберите цикл с `raws[i].Replace` вообще. Всё равно будет false. Намёк ясен?

Comment: @ZverevEugene, т.е. то что я сравниваю два массива, на самом деле массивами не является? Я сравниваю просто имена?

Comment: @Jalt Что вы имеете в виду, когда говорите: "сравниваю просто имена", не понятно. Array.Equals сравнивает ссыки, а не содержимое массивов. Смотрите ответы на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написал @free_ze, метод [Array.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) не имеет никакого отношения к сравнению данных массива. Этот метод сравнивает, являются ли указанные аргументы ссылками на один и тот же массив.

Чтобы сравнить элементы массивов используйте хотя бы [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423318/how-to-compare-arrays-in-c):

> bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(target1, target2);

Однако, обратите винмание, что в вашем коде есть ещё одна проблема. Когда вы **копируете ссылки** на `StringBuilder`, а потом меняете значение содержимого `StringBuilder` при помощи метода `Replace`, то меняются данные объекта, на который сслается и первый массив и **копия**.

Правильнее сказать, что вы не создаёте копию набора `StringBuilder`, вы создаёте копию ссылок на них.

Не путайте `StringBuilder.Replace` и `string.replace`. Это совершенно разные вещи. `StringBuilder.Replace` меняет содержимое себя и возвращает ссылку на себя же, вне зависимости от того, нашлось что-то для замены или нет. `string.replace` создаёт новую строку и возвращает ссылку на неё, если нашлось что поменять, а если не нашлось, то возвращает ссылку на себя.

Если бы вы работали с массивами ссылок на `System.String`, то у ваш код заработал бы как ожидалось.

Если работать надо именно с классом `StringBuilder` то при создании копии надо использовать что-то вроде:

```
for(int index = 0; index < raws.Length; index++)
{
    raws1[index] = new StringBuilder(raws[index].ToString());
}
```

Обратите внимание, что при такой тактике, вы будете подвержены ещё одной потенциальной проблеме. А именно, метод [StringBuilder.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccth01t4(v=vs.110).aspx) сравнивает не только строку, которая в нём хранится, но так же свойства `Capacity`, и  `MaxCapacity`, которые могут меняться в процессе манипуляций со строками внутри `StringBuilder`.

В вашем примере, когда исходная строка подвергается только одному нехитрому изменению, эта проблема может вас и не затронет, но это бомба замедленного действия. Не делайте так. Любой грамотный программист увидит этот код и составит о вас нелецеприятное мнение.

Comment: Теперь после использования этого метода мы всегда получаем `true` 
Т.е. после замены OO на ++, при сравнении, `isEqual = true`, хотя, логично что должно быть `false`

Comment: И это правильно. Тут проявляется ваша вторая ошибка. StringBuilder, в отличаи от string, не является немутируемым объектом.

Comment: понял, что мы не копируем один массив в другой, а присваиваем ссылку. Как правильно скопировать тогда? Через `for (int i = 0....`?

Answer (score 2):

`Array.Equals` наследуется от `Object`, т.е. сравнивает ссылки на объекты массивов.

Comment: тут кстати пока непонятно, что за метод Equals используется

Comment: @Grundy, `Array.Equals(raws1,raws)` сравниваю 2 одномерных массива, внутри которых StringBuilder строки.

Comment: @free_ze, так вроде там и есть ссылки, я же изменяю массив на который ссылаются.

Comment: @Jalt Ссылки на разные массивы, даже если они содержат одинаковые данные, будут разными. [был такой же вопросец на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423318/how-to-compare-arrays-in-c)

Comment: @Jalt Можете попробовать [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) для этих целей.

Comment: @free_ze, понял ошибку. Теперь осталось разобрать что есть ссылка, что есть объект и что от чего наследуется.

Comment: @Jalt Вам поможет [Рихтер](https://vk.com/doc-69403680_286821784?dl=fd233d5c010bb6e6be)

Answer (score 0):

Дабы избежать работы с ссылками, пришлось уйти от StrinBuilder'a и сделать все через строки. Тем самым, сравнение происходит корректно. 
Спасибо @ZverevEugene и @free_ze.

```
     `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           str1[i] = raws[i].Replace("OO", "++");
        }
      bool isEqual=Enumerable.SequenceEqual(str1, raws); `
```

Comment: Выберите ответ, который вам больше нравится примите его. Так работает StackOverflow. Это поможет другим пользователям видеть, какое решение отвечает поставленной задаче.